# Implementing a grpc client in C# .Net Framework that connects to a Python 3 grpc server?

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, grpc, grpc-python

I am trying to write a grpc client in C# .Net Framework (4.7.x) that's supposed to connect to a Python (3.7) grpc server running on a RaspberryPi.
To ensure that my proto file is correct and that the communcation between the computers is ok, I have managed to successfully run it with an insecure Python client and server set up.
As far as I been able to find out, C# has no support for connections without SSL, so now I have ended up in writing a Python server that supports SSL, generated the certs and now I'm stuck with the client in C#.

When I run the client I get the error:

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Unimplemented",
> Detail=""b'/AaesIoServer.Board/GetDigital'" requires exactly one
> request message.")' and on the server side I get: 28997
> hpack_parser.cc:1218] Error parsing metadata: error=invalid value
> key=content-type value=application/grpc-web-text

This is obviously because I use "GrpcWebMode = GrpcWebMode.GrpcWebText" in my "GrpcWbHandler" on the client side, but if I try with the other option "GrpcWebMode = GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb" (or running without setting the GrpcWebMode), I get the follwing error on the client:

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Unauthenticated",
> Detail="Invalid signature")' and on the server side I get: 28997
> hpack_parser.cc:1218] Error parsing metadata: error=invalid value
> key=content-type value=application/grpc-web

The certificate are self-signed generated with openssl.

What am I missing here?

The code looks as follows:

Client:

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await DoCall(args[0]);
        }

        static async Task DoCall(string url)
        {
            var httpHandler = new WinHttpHandler() 
            { 
                ServerCertificateValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
            };
            httpHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("sslCred\\server.crt"));
            var handler = new GrpcWebHandler()
            {
                GrpcWebMode = GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb,
                InnerHandler = httpHandler
            };
            using (var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(new Uri(String.Format("https://{0}", url)), new GrpcChannelOptions() {HttpHandler = handler}))
            {
                var client = new Board.BoardClient(channel);
                var digitalRequest = new GetDigitalRequest() { PinName = "digital_out0" };

                var response = await client.GetDigitalAsync(digitalRequest);
                Console.WriteLine("Get digital response received: " + response.Result);
            }

        }
    }
```

Server:

```py
import grpc
from concurrent import futures
import time
from BoardApi import Board
import argparse
from concurrent import futures
import contextlib
import logging
import _credentials
import grpc

AaesIoDefinition_pb2, AaesIoDefinition_pb2_grpc = grpc.protos_and_services(
    "AaesIoDefinition.proto")

_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
_LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)

_LISTEN_ADDRESS_TEMPLATE = '111.111.11.111:%d'
_SIGNATURE_HEADER_KEY = 'x-signature'


class SignatureValidationInterceptor(grpc.ServerInterceptor):

    def __init__(self):

        def abort(ignored_request, context):
            context.abort(grpc.StatusCode.UNAUTHENTICATED, 'Invalid signature')

        self._abortion = grpc.unary_unary_rpc_method_handler(abort)

    def intercept_service(self, continuation, handler_call_details):
        method_name = handler_call_details.method.split('/')[-1]
        expected_metadata = (_SIGNATURE_HEADER_KEY, method_name[::-1])
        if expected_metadata in handler_call_details.invocation_metadata:
            return continuation(handler_call_details)
        else:
            return self._abortion



@contextlib.contextmanager
def run_server(port):

    
    # Bind interceptor to server
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(),
                        interceptors=(SignatureValidationInterceptor(),))
    AaesIoDefinition_pb2_grpc.add_BoardServicer_to_server(Board(), server)

    # Loading credentials
    server_credentials = grpc.ssl_server_credentials(((
        read_cert()[0],
        read_cert()[1],
    ),))

    port = server.add_secure_port(_LISTEN_ADDRESS_TEMPLATE % port,
                                server_credentials)

    server.start()
    try:
        yield server, port
    finally:
        server.stop(0)


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--port',
                        nargs='?',
                        type=int,
                        default=50051,
                        help='the listening port')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    with run_server(args.port) as (server, port):
        logging.info('Server is listening at port :%d', port)
        server.wait_for_termination()

def read_cert():
    with open('_credentials/server.key', 'rb') as f:
        private_key = f.read()
    with open('_credentials/server.crt', 'rb') as f:
        certificate_chain = f.read()
    return private_key, certificate_chain

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    main()
```

Comment: "As far as I been able to find out, C# has no support for connections without SSL" - it should be possible, but we can't tell what you've tried or what happened. At the moment you appear to be trying to use an https URL, so that *would* have SSL...

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment. I don't remember exactly what error message I got when I tried, but if I look at Microsofts documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/netstandard?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-7.0
Under the section ".Net Framework", it says: "Only gRPC calls over TLS are supported."

Comment: @NiklasAtHouseOfTest it works just fine without TLS on both the Google and Microsoft implementations; it looks like you're using .NET as the client here and the Microsoft transport; I *expect* what you need is [this switch](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/blob/e407274506baed4a0d8e53553eb5b31df2a1b74b/src/protobuf-net.Grpc/Client/GrpcClientFactory.cs#L28); now - back to the original thing: are you actually *using* grpc-web?  this looks like vanilla grpc to me - in which case you can just use `GrpcChannel.ForAddress` and not deal with all the handler bits manually

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarcGravell! You're right, my intention was to use plain vanilla grpc. I want to keep the code as simple as possible. I'm pretty new to this and I didn't know about grpc-web until I got tangled up in this. ;-)  
The switch you're suggesting sounds absolutely right, but I'm not sure how to use it my case. All examples I've found, are using ASP.NET. When I try in my code (.net framework 4.7.2), the switch AllowUnencryptedHttp2 isn't available in neither GrpcClientFactory nor GrpcClientFactoryOptions. You wouldn't happen to know about any other, more suitable examples somewhere?

Comment: Just copy the code out from what I've linked you, and call the method on System AppContext directly. That property is also available in protobuf-net.Grpc, but adding a package just for this one line seems overkill

Comment: Literally: `AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);`

Comment: I have tried some more now, unfortunately without success. The "AppContext.SetSwitch" approach in my the example I provided still fails. 
If I instead switch to an "insecure" server and use the "protobuf-net" libs, and use an adapted version of the example https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/blob/main/examples/pb-net-grpc/Client_CS/Program.cs, I get an error message saying: ...The configured HTTP provider must either support HTTP/2 or be configured to use gRPC-Web...

Comment: cont...This led me to this site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/netstandard?view=aspnetcore-7.0 where they suggest using Grpc-web for creating a handler in the GrpcWebOptions.
Applying this to the insecure example gives me another error message: 
StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. WebException: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine" which is not very helpful to me. No messages on the server side with this...